# ETA of Cosmos DB Autopilot being available for existing database/ARM template

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When will autopilot available for existing database and containers?
When will autopilot available to be configured by ARM template?
Is there ETA for these features? We need to decide whether to wait for the official autopilot or implement it by ourselves if it takes long time before GA.

Answer (score 1):

ARM support for AutoPilot, as well as migration capability for existing database and container resources will be available when this feature goes GA.

We are not disclosing the exact date for GA but it will be fairly soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is now GA, the ARM template below works for me.

[Create an Azure Cosmos DB account for Core (SQL) API with autoscale](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-cosmosdb-sql-autoscale/azuredeploy.json)

Answer (score 0):

I still get 'Error updating offer for resource dbs/... {"code":500,"body":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"An unknown error occurred while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact Azure Support:

Existing container, UK South